# How can I show the arrows at the ends of an hScrollBar when the cursor is not over it?

Tags: winforms, scrollbar

I have a C# Winforms project using VS 2022 using an hScrollBar control. The default behaviour is that the arrows at each end of the control are only shown when the cursor is over the control as as shown below.
[image: Scroll bar with end arrows visible]

Can I make the arrows visible when the cursor is not over the control without creating arrow images, placing them over the ends of the control and making them visible when the cursor enters the control and invisible when it leaves, and passing the click event to the scrollbar?

Comment: See the example [ScrollBarRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollbarrenderer?view=netframework-4.8). It covers the paint part only. Needs to add properties (Value, Minimum, Maximum, SmallChange, LargeChange...etc.), and calculate the thumb size accordingly, event (ValueChanged or Scroll). Don't draw the buttons if their rectangles don't contain the mouse position.